# Input dimension error on pytorch's forward check

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch

I am creating an *RNN* with `pytorch`, it looks like this:

```
class MyRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, batch_size, n_inputs, n_neurons, n_outputs):
        super(MyRNN, self).__init__()

        self.n_neurons = n_neurons
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_inputs = n_inputs
        self.n_outputs = n_outputs

        self.basic_rnn = nn.RNN(self.n_inputs, self.n_neurons)

        self.FC = nn.Linear(self.n_neurons, self.n_outputs)

    def init_hidden(self, ):
        # (num_layers, batch_size, n_neurons)
        return torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.n_neurons)

    def forward(self, X):
        self.batch_size = X.size(0)
        self.hidden = self.init_hidden()

        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.basic_rnn(X, self.hidden)
        out = self.FC(self.hidden)

        return out.view(-1, self.n_outputs)
```

My input `x` looks like this:

```
tensor([[-1.0173e-04, -1.5003e-04, -1.0218e-04, -7.4541e-05, -2.2869e-05,
         -7.7171e-02, -4.4630e-03, -5.0750e-05, -1.7911e-04, -2.8082e-04,
         -9.2992e-06, -1.5608e-05, -3.5471e-05, -4.9127e-05, -3.2883e-01],
        [-1.1193e-04, -1.6928e-04, -1.0218e-04, -7.4541e-05, -2.2869e-05,
         -7.7171e-02, -4.4630e-03, -5.0750e-05, -1.7911e-04, -2.8082e-04,
         -9.2992e-06, -1.5608e-05, -3.5471e-05, -4.9127e-05, -3.2883e-01],
        ...

        [-6.9490e-05, -8.9197e-05, -1.0218e-04, -7.4541e-05, -2.2869e-05,
         -7.7171e-02, -4.4630e-03, -5.0750e-05, -1.7911e-04, -2.8082e-04,
         -9.2992e-06, -1.5608e-05, -3.5471e-05, -4.9127e-05, -3.2883e-01]],
       dtype=torch.float64)
```

and is a batch of 64 vectors with size 15.

When trying to test this model by doing:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
N_INPUTS = 15
N_NEURONS = 150
N_OUTPUTS = 1
model = MyRNN(BATCH_SIZE, N_INPUTS, N_NEURONS, N_OUTPUTS)
model(x)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/home/tt/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 126, in check_forward_args
    expected_input_dim, input.dim()))
RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Seeing as me and @Erik have different interpretations, do you have sequences of length 15 and one feature at each time step, or 1 timestep and 15 features? In the latter case, an RNN doesn't really make sense

Comment: @Coolness I have 15 features for each time step, my reasoning for using an RNN, apart from trying to learn, is that I eventually add multiple timesteps, with 15 features each. But for the moment I only have that 64x15 input. Do you suggest some other model for this specific data set? If yes should I better rephrase the question so you can answer that?

Comment: @dearn44 What multiple time steps do you add and when?

Comment: I updated my answer. Just add a single leading dimension to your input.

Comment: @Erik, right now I am only using 15 features for lets say 64 companies for this month. I have similar data for the previous 12 months that I will eventually use, so my data set in reality is 64x15x12, but given that I want to learn PyTorch I thought about using only the data for one month.

Comment: @dearn44 Makes sense, but in this case I’d suggest you use at least two months. The benefit of the RNN in this case is that the model has “memory” about what happened in previous months and can use that information when predicting the next month (or whatever you are trying to infer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one of the required dimensions for the RNN layer.

Per the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.RNN), your input size needs to be of shape (sequence length, batch, input size).

So - with the example above, you are missing one of these. Based on your variable names, it appears you are trying to pass 64 examples of 15 inputs each... if that’s true, you are missing sequence length.

With an RNN, the sequence length is the number of times you want the layer to recur. For example, in NLP your sequence length might be equal to the number of words in a sentence, while batch size would be the number of sentences you are passing, and input size would be the vector size of each word.

You might not need an RNN here if you are just trying to do use 64 samples of size 15.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html), the RNN layer expects

> input of shape (seq_len, batch, input_size): tensor containing the features of the input sequence.

<s>In your case it seems that your "size" is the length of the sequence, and you have one feature at every timestep.</s> Edited for 15 features, one timestep

```
# 15 features, 150 neurons
rnn = nn.RNN(15, 150)
# sequence of length 1, batch size 64, 15 features
x = torch.rand(1, 64, 15)
res, _ = rnn(x)
print(res.shape)
# => torch.Size([1, 64, 150])

Also note that you don't need to prespecify batch size.
```